# How to add New Ethernet Interface and connect it to the WiFi interface on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server?

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, interface

So for one of software that I want to use I need 2 Ethernet interfaces.

One will be used for internet connection (eth0, dhcp and connected to internet router), and the other for connecting to other devices (eth1, static ip). These eth interfaces will be detected during installation.

But what I have to use is a Mini PC with only one WiFi Interface and one Ethernet Port.

I am thinking of creating a Virtual Eth (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152334/512125), then connect it to the WiFi Interface to get internet connection, and finally rename the existing ethernet port. Though I still need to find out the method to connect them.

So my question would be, How do I make a new ethernet interface, connect it the wifi interface, and make this setting persistent?

Comment: You can add a USB Ethernet adapter.

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes, we have been using USB Ethernet Adapter previously. Though, I am looking for a way as outlined in the question in case it is not possible.